# Read PowerPoint Notes Slides Headers Footers using OpenXML

Tags: c#, powerpoint, interop, openxml

I can read all texts in all slides in powerPoint file, but I can't read the NotesSlides in PPT using OpenXML.

I am trying to read the Headers and Footers of NotesSlide. Not the Slides.

Anyone can help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4URm.png)